# How to loosen a stuck screw on iPhone 8?

Tags: iphone, repair

I wanted to replace the screen on an iPhone 8 and failed at the first step: One of the screws next to lightning port is stuck.

[image]

The one the right comes off fine, while the one on the left doesn't provide a hold for the screwdriver. I can spin the screwdriver forever without loosening the screw. There was a little bit of grip at my first intent, but even that's gone by now. It seems I've worsened the problem.

What are my options?

Comment: I have **NO** idea if these are small enough (probably not) but "broken screw removers" is what you want to search for. https://www.amazon.com/Silver-Damaged-Stripped-Extractor-Remover/dp/B0CMDMZNFB/ref=asc_df_B0CMDMZNFB&mcid=aa7027a0afa5336894417531cabebd1e?tag=bngsmtphsnus-20&linkCode=df0&hvadid=80745516799947&hvnetw=s&hvqmt=e&hvbmt=be&hvdev=c&hvlocint=&hvlocphy=&hvtargid=pla-4584345042894363&psc=1 That is assuming the head is stripped out but the screw itself is OK.

Comment: Put the screwdriver in, then carefully fill it with electronics solder, let it solidify without removing the screwdriver and try again